How do I put a limit to groups?
This is my first day of learning Python and my very first project. so i have 62 items in my data and want it to randomly pick out 48 of them and put them each in a group of 4. So a total of 48 in 12 different groups of 4. It keeps putting 16 groups with 4 countries in each and 2 countries in the last group. How do I fix this or limit the groups?
import random

countries = [ 'Argentina','France', 'Belgium',  'England','Brazil', 'Portugal', 'Netherlands',  'Spain',    'Italy',    'Croatia',  'United_States',    'Colombia', 'Morocco',  'Mexico',   'Uruguay',  'Germany','Senegal','Japan',    'Switzerland', 'Iran',  'Denmark',  'Ukraine', 'South_Korea',   'Australia',    'Austria', 'Hungary',   'Sweden', 'Poland', 'Wales',    'Nigeria',  'Ecuador',  'Peru',     'Serbia',   'Qatar',    'Russia',   'Czech_Republic', 'Czechia',    'Egypt',    'Ivory_Coast',  'Scotland', 'Türkiye',  'Tunisia',  'Chile',    'Algeria',  'Mali',     'Panama',   'Romania',  'Norway',   'Slovakia',     'Canada',   'Greece', 'Cameroon',   'Costa_Rica',   'Saudi_Arabia',     'Venezuela',    'Jamaica', 'Paraguay', 'Slovenia',  'Iraq','South_Africa',  'Republic_of_Ireland',  'Finland']

group = 1
membersInGroup = 4

for country in countries [:]:
    if membersInGroup == 4 :
        print ("group {} consist of:" .format(group))
        membersInGroup = 0
        group += 1

person = random.choice (countries)
print (person)
membersInGroup += 1
countries.remove (str(person))`

I don't know all the terminology of coding, so I feel limited in myself.

Please fix the indentation of the code in the post. And there seems to be code missing. Where are you actually creating any groups? Or only picking out 48?

items = random.choices(countries, k=48), group1 = items[:4], group2 = items[4:8], etc.

You can use random.sample to pick 48 random countries from the input list, and then use itertools.batched to transform the list into a sequence of groups of 4:
from random import sample
from itertools import batched

print(*batched(sample(countries, 48), 4), sep='\n')

Demo here

Check out the following script:
import random

# List of countries
countries = ['Argentina', 'France', 'Belgium', 'England', 'Brazil', 'Portugal', 'Netherlands', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'Croatia', 'United_States', 'Colombia', 'Morocco', 'Mexico', 'Uruguay', 'Germany', 'Senegal', 'Japan', 'Switzerland', 'Iran', 'Denmark', 'Ukraine', 'South_Korea', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Hungary', 'Sweden', 'Poland', 'Wales', 'Nigeria', 'Ecuador', 'Peru', 'Serbia', 'Qatar', 'Russia', 'Czech_Republic', 'Czechia', 'Egypt', 'Ivory_Coast', 'Scotland', 'Türkiye', 'Tunisia', 'Chile', 'Algeria', 'Mali', 'Panama', 'Romania', 'Norway', 'Slovakia', 'Canada', 'Greece', 'Cameroon', 'Costa_Rica', 'Saudi_Arabia', 'Venezuela', 'Jamaica', 'Paraguay', 'Slovenia', 'Iraq', 'South_Africa', 'Republic_of_Ireland', 'Finland']

# Dictionary to store groups
groups = {}

# Initialize group number and member count
group = 1
membersInGroup = 0

# Loop until all 12 groups are created
while group <= 12:
    # List to store members of the current group
    group_members = []
    # Loop until each group has 4 members
    while membersInGroup < 4:
        # Check if there are no more countries to allocate
        if not countries:
            break
        # Randomly choose a country from the list
        person = random.choice(countries)
        # Add the chosen country to the current group
        group_members.append(person)
        # Remove the chosen country from the list of countries
        countries.remove(person)
        # Increment the member count for the current group
        membersInGroup += 1
    # Store the current group and its members in the dictionary
    groups[group] = group_members
    # Move to the next group
    group += 1
    # Reset the member count for the next group
    membersInGroup = 0

# Print groups with group number and list of members
for group_num, group_members in groups.items():
    print("Group {} consists of:".format(group_num))
    for member in group_members:
        print(member)
    print()


You can use sample(data, k=48) to get all 48 random items at once.
And later you can slice it groups[i+1] = items[ i*4 : (i+1)*4 ]
if you are not sure if it is random enough then you can also use shuffle to change order on list.
(it works in-place so don't assign to variable)
import random

countries = [ 'Argentina','France', 'Belgium',  'England','Brazil', 'Portugal', 'Netherlands',  'Spain',    'Italy',    'Croatia',  'United_States',    'Colombia', 'Morocco',  'Mexico',   'Uruguay',  'Germany','Senegal','Japan',    'Switzerland', 'Iran',  'Denmark',  'Ukraine', 'South_Korea',   'Australia',    'Austria', 'Hungary',   'Sweden', 'Poland', 'Wales',    'Nigeria',  'Ecuador',  'Peru',     'Serbia',   'Qatar',    'Russia',   'Czech_Republic', 'Czechia',    'Egypt',    'Ivory_Coast',  'Scotland', 'Türkiye',  'Tunisia',  'Chile',    'Algeria',  'Mali',     'Panama',   'Romania',  'Norway',   'Slovakia',     'Canada',   'Greece', 'Cameroon',   'Costa_Rica',   'Saudi_Arabia',     'Venezuela',    'Jamaica', 'Paraguay', 'Slovenia',  'Iraq','South_Africa',  'Republic_of_Ireland',  'Finland']

import random

items = random.sample(countries, k=48)
random.shuffle(items)  # optional, (it works `in-place` so don't assign to variable)

groups = {}

for i in range(12):
    groups[i+1] = items[i*4:(i+1)*4]
   
# --- display ---
 
for key, val in groups.items():    
    print(key, val)

Example result (without using shuffle)

1 ['Republic_of_Ireland', 'Norway', 'Costa_Rica', 'Panama']
2 ['Mali', 'Chile', 'Egypt', 'Nigeria']
3 ['Australia', 'Saudi_Arabia', 'Finland', 'Tunisia']
4 ['Spain', 'Hungary', 'Japan', 'Greece']
5 ['Poland', 'Slovakia', 'Ivory_Coast', 'Serbia']
6 ['Uruguay', 'Türkiye', 'Belgium', 'Netherlands']
7 ['Denmark', 'England', 'Venezuela', 'Czechia']
8 ['France', 'South_Korea', 'Jamaica', 'Iraq']
9 ['Germany', 'South_Africa', 'Sweden', 'Algeria']
10 ['Russia', 'Romania', 'Wales', 'Iran']
11 ['Cameroon', 'Scotland', 'Peru', 'Portugal']
12 ['Slovenia', 'Colombia', 'Paraguay', 'Morocco']


You can even use dictionary comprehension and you will need only two lines:
items = random.sample(countries, k=48)

groups = {i+1:items[i*4:(i+1)*4] for i in range(12)}

